# got Undefined variable: when i try to make picklist

Tags: php, laravel-5, picklist

I wanna make a modal picklist form. Here is my controller:

```
public function picklist(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    $lists = Customer::where('name', 'like', "%$q%")
        ->orderBy('name')->paginate('5');
    return view('customer._customer_list')
        ->with('lists', $lists);

}
```

and this is view _customer_list.blade.php

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($lists as $key => $list)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $list->name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-choose" 
                        type="button" data-id="{{ $list->id }}" data-name="{{ $list->name }}">Pilih</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! $lists->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/customer/list/', 'PurchasesController@picklist');
```

when i open localhost/customer/list
it worked

but when i try to passing to another view like this

```
@section('content-modal')   
@include('purchase.modal_picklist', [
    'name' => 'customer',
    'title' => 'Daftar Customer',
    'placeholder' => 'Cari customer berdasarkan nama',
])
@endsection

@section('content-js')
@include('customer._customer_list')
<script>
    CreatePicklist('customer', '/customer/list?');
</script>   
@endsection
```

with route like this
Route::get('/customer/add', 'CustomerController@create');

I got error:

> Undefined variable: lists (View: /srv/web/resources/views/customer/_customer_list.blade.php) (View: /srv/web/resources/views/customer/_customer_list.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined variable: lists (View: /srv/web/resources/views/customer/_customer_list.blade.php) (View: /srv/web/resources/views/customer/_customer_list.blade.php)

This error means in your view (in foreach loop) blade cannot get list variable.

Try render view with giving parameter as second argument, something like below

```
public function picklist(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    $lists = Customer::where('name', 'like', "%$q%")
        ->orderBy('name')->paginate('5');
    return view('customer._customer_list', ['lists' => $lists]);
}
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: ive been try, but it still giving error undifined variable.

Comment: Of course you will get an error because when you are including @include('customer._customer_list') in another blade that time you are not passing any parameter to  **customer._customer_list** blade. you need to pass **list** variable with something like **@include('customer._customer_list', [
        'lists' => "your list"]);**

Comment: i try like this, @section('content-js')
    @include('customer._customer_list',[ 'lists' => "lists"])
    <script>
        CreatePicklist('customer', '/customer/list?');
    </script>   
@endsection

but i get error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /srv/web/resources/views/customer/_customer_list.blade.php)

Comment: so i think, i will remove @foreach on _customer_list.blade.php. but its still give me error undifined variable lists